# Python script cannot use check_output when used through cron at reboot

Tags: python, cron

I am a total beginner and wanted to play around with Python's check_output function.

I have a user based cron job that opens a bash file which in turn opens a Python script to be executed on boot up. I am running my Raspberry pi headless but am using screen to be able to check up on the Python process if I wanted to SSH in.

My user crontab looks like this and starts perfectly fine as the Python script actually starts and almost works.

```
@reboot sleep 30 && sh /home/pi/launcher.sh  >>/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

This is the bash file that starts screen and then the Python script

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -h 500 -S Telegram -d -m /usr/bin/python /home/pi/telegram/bot2.py
```

This is the Python file that has the issues. I can start it just fine and can verify that it is working. But check_output gives me an error.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import time
    import telepot
    from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
    from subprocess import call
    from subprocess import check_output
    from subprocess import CalledProcessError

    print 'Hello'

    def handle(msg):
        chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
        command = msg['text']

        print 'Got command: %s' % command

        if command == 'Status':
                    try:
                            result = check_output(['service','hostapd','status'])
                    except CalledProcessError as exc:
                            result = exc.output


MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print 'I am listening ...'

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

This is the error I get. Interestingly, simple call processes do not give me that error and are working fine.

```
Got command: Status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/telepot/loop.py", line 37, in run_forever
    self._handle(msg)
  File "/home/pi/telegram/bot2.py", line 31, in handle
    result = check_output(['service','hostapd','status'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I hope someone can help me. I have a feeling that it has something to do with permissions or environments on boot.

It is very important to add that the whole thing works like a charm when I go in manually and start the bash file myself when I'm logged in.

**EDIT:** I did some poking around and I get a different error now:

```
Got command: Status
/bin/sh: 1: service: not found
```

I **changed the command** in the Python script to

```
result = check_output(["service hostapd status"], shell=True )
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out !!!:

The reason behind why it worked is still obscure but it has empiricly worked out so im happy.

The fix was to change the check_output command from the original

```
result = check_output(['service','hostapd','status'])
```

to the now working

```
result = check_output(["/usr/sbin/service hostapd status"], shell=True )
```

first the `shell=True` part was necessary then a quick search with `which service` gave me the location for the service "service". After that phython was pleased.

The weirdest thing about this whole thing is that phython had no problem with an expression that i used in a latter part of the same phython script.

```
call(["sudo","service","hostapd","start"])
```

EDIT: Now that i researched this to write that answer i realised that the call fuction had a small "sudo" that my check_output didnt have.

EDIT: So of course i went back and modified the check_output function to also have a simple sudo and it freaking worked without the hassle of the shell=True and what so ever.

**FINAL SOLUTION** that worked for me :

change

```
result = check_output(['service','hostapd','status'])
```

to

```
result = check_output(['sudo','service','hostapd','status'])
```